# GeoNode Layer overview Legend not displaying

Tags: geonode

The Geonode documentation indicates that once a layer has been uploaded a Legend can be seen, however I am unable to see the legend in the layer overview page nor can I find a reason/error for it not to display.

Is there a setting that needs to be configured during setup in order to see the Legend or can someone maybe point me in the direction of the server log(s) where I might be able to see why this isn't displaying as expected.

**Screenshot of Geonode documentation showing the legend**
[image: Geonode Documentation]

**Screenshort of my test server not showing the legend**
[image: My test server]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long back and forth on the dev list I was advised to start from scratch.
Not sure if installing the Geonode Core made the difference, but reinstalling and configuring everything seemd to have fixed the problem.

The layer legend is now being displayed!

** **Things to note:**

1. I was unable to `workon geonode` after creating the `virtualenv` with `virtualenv geonode`, I had to do the following: `source geonode/bin/activate` in order to work on it, escaping the virt env was accomplished with `deactivate` while in the virt env. I ran into segmentation faults and other issues during installation beacause I wasn't in the virtual environment.  [Link to original answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654449/error-segmentation-fault-core-dumped/55954196#comment104299248_55954196) that helped me get it resolved.
2. The SSL steps in the documentation I had to do in reverse as the first time it caused links to be broken and I couldn't update Geoserver settings. I first had to update Genode and Geoserver before installing the SSL.